# Convert lat/lng to pixel in UTM image files

Tags: latitude-longitude, utm, pixel

This is my first post on this site so please be gentle :)

I have a number of large image files that map locations around the world. These image files are in UTM projection and I am looking to write a simple algorithm that converts a lat/lng to a filename and then an x, y co-ordinate representing a pixel in the image file.

I would also like an equivalent algorithm that takes a filename and x, y co-ordinate as input and returns a lat/lng as output, although this is less essential.

Also, if converting a lat/lng to a filename is too tricky then I would settle for just having the algorithm return a pixel value (assuming you somehow manually point it to the correct image file).

Here is all the information I think may be relevant (but please let me know if more is required):

- The image files are in PNG format
- Each pixel represents 30 metres
- The co-ordinate system is WGS84
- The files depict information as follows:
- From 60° N - 60° S: 5° (latitude) * 6° (longitude)
- From 60 - 80° N and 60 - 80° S: 5° (latitude) * 12° (longitude)
- The starting latitude for files in the northern hemisphere is the lower left corner of the file, while for the southern hemisphere it is the top right corner of the file
- As an example, the filename which contains Sydney, Australia is s56_30 while the filename which contains Miami, USA is n17_25

My preference is to first write my algorithm in PHP, but I will also be writing a JavaScript version. For the purposes of this answer, pseudo-code will be fine. Does such an algorithm already exist?

Comment: This is pretty trivial using a library designed for coordinate transformation (reprojection).  However, there is quite a bit of maths if you decide to reinvent the wheel... I suggest you see what libraries are available.  There's also some PHP & JS code in answers to a [Stack Overflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9203295/737471) though I can't comment on their quality.

Comment: Two examples aren't enough to establish a pattern, perhaps you could create a fishnet spanning 0 to 360 by 60 to -60 in 6 x 5 cells in geographic coordinates then look at the known maps and establish your naming convention.. from there a lookup isn't too difficult to work out what raster you're referencing then locate a pixel using the offset from the origin. Hint: raster files are almost always upper left registered with the Y cell size being negative. GDAL would probably be a good place to start, it contains Proj.4 library for coordinate transformation and is  very mature and stable.